# Python Sorting Algorithm Visualizer with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, data-visualization

So I've written a Sorting Algorithms Visualizer according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twRidO-_vqQ) tutorial, but made some changes and add some features of my own.

The visualization is made with Pygame (Which I never used before).

The interface allows to:

- Start sorting by pressing the space bar
- Change between ascending and descending order by pressing A or D
- Reset the array by pressing R
- Generate a new array by pressing N
- Choose between Insertion sort (I), Heap Sort (H), and Bubble Sort (B)

My concerns are:

1. Did I use `yield` correctly, especially in the heap sort.
2. I choose to add the drawing functions to the `DrawAttributes`, is it a good choice?
3. To make sure that I don't draw over the different times, I've created the `SortingTimes` class. Is there a better way to do it?
4. Last but not least, I'm measuring the time by calling `time.perf_counter()` at the start and end of each sorting algorithm, I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it while using pygame to illustrate each iteration.

Another issue which is not a proper code review - somehow pressing on the space bar after finishing a Heap Sort restarts the sorting, which doesn't happen with the two others

The code:

```
import sys
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()


class DrawAttributes:
    BLACK = 0, 0, 0
    WHITE = 255, 255, 255
    GREEN = 0, 255, 0
    RED = 255, 0, 0
    BACKGROUND_COLOR = WHITE

    GRADIENT = [
        (128, 128, 128),
        (160, 160, 160),
        (192, 192, 192)
    ]
    SMALL_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Helvetica', 15)
    FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Helvetica', 25)
    LARGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Helvetica', 40)
    SIDE_PAD = 100  # padding for both left and right sides, combined
    TOP_PAD = 150

    def __init__(self, width, height, lst):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sorting Algorithms Visualizer")
        self.set_list(lst)

    def set_list(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.max_val = max(lst)
        self.min_val = min(lst)

        self.block_width = (self.width - self.SIDE_PAD) // len(lst)
        self.block_height = (self.height - self.TOP_PAD) // (self.max_val - self.min_val)
        self.start_x = self.SIDE_PAD // 2

    def draw(self, algo_name, ascending, s_times):
        self.window.fill(self.BACKGROUND_COLOR)

        title = self.LARGE_FONT.render(f"{algo_name} - {'Ascending' if ascending else 'Descending'}",
                                       True, self.GREEN)
        self.window.blit(title, (self.width / 2 - title.get_width() / 2, 5))

        controls = self.FONT.render("N - New | R - Reset | SPACE - Start Sorting | A - Ascending | D - Descending",
                                    True,
                                    self.BLACK)
        self.window.blit(controls, (self.width / 2 - controls.get_width() / 2, 50))

        algorithms = self.FONT.render("I - Insertion Sort | H - Heap Sort | B - Bubble Sort", True, self.BLACK)
        self.window.blit(algorithms, (self.width / 2 - algorithms.get_width() / 2, 80))

        self.draw_list()
        self.draw_times(s_times)
        pygame.display.update()

    def draw_list(self, color_position=None, clear_bg=False):
        if color_position is None:
            color_position = {}
        lst = self.lst

        if clear_bg:
            clear_rect = (self.SIDE_PAD // 2, self.TOP_PAD, self.width - self.SIDE_PAD,
                          self.height - self.TOP_PAD)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.window, self.BACKGROUND_COLOR, clear_rect)

        for i, val in enumerate(lst):
            x = self.start_x + i * self.block_width
            y = self.height - (val - self.min_val) * self.block_height

            color = self.GRADIENT[i % 3]

            if i in color_position:
                color = color_position[i]

            pygame.draw.rect(self.window, color, (x, y, self.block_width, self.height))

        if clear_bg:
            pygame.display.update()

    def draw_times(self, s_times=None):

        time_blit = self.SMALL_FONT.render(f"{s_times.insertion}{'s' if s_times.insertion else ''} | "
                                           f"{s_times.heap}{'s' if s_times.heap else ''} | "
                                           f"{s_times.bubble}{'s' if s_times.bubble else ''}"
                                           , True, self.BLACK)
        self.window.blit(time_blit, (self.width / 2 - time_blit.get_width() / 2, 110))


class SortingTimes:

    bubble = None
    heap = None
    insertion = None

    def clear(self):
        self.bubble = None
        self.heap = None
        self.insertion = None


def generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val, same_sid=False, seed=None):
    if not same_sid:
        seed = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)

    random.seed(seed)
    lst = random.sample(range(min_val, max_val), n)

    return lst, seed


def insertion_sort(draw_attr, s_times, ascending=True):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    lst = draw_attr.lst

    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        curr = lst[i]

        while True:
            ascending_sort = i > 0 and lst[i - 1] > curr and ascending
            descending_sort = i > 0 and lst[i - 1] < curr and not ascending

            if not ascending_sort and not descending_sort:
                break

            lst[i] = lst[i - 1]
            i -= 1
            lst[i] = curr
            draw_attr.draw_list({i: draw_attr.GREEN, i - 1: draw_attr.RED}, True)
            yield True

    s_times.insertion = round(time.perf_counter() - start, 2)
    draw_attr.draw_times(s_times)


def heapify(draw_attr, n, i, ascending):
    lst = draw_attr.lst

    curr = i
    left = 2 * i + 1
    right = 2 * i + 2

    if ascending:
        if left < n and lst[curr] < lst[left]:
            curr = left

        if right < n and lst[curr] < lst[right]:
            curr = right

    if not ascending:
        if left < n and lst[left] < lst[curr]:
            curr = left

        if right < n and lst[right] < lst[curr]:
            curr = right

    if curr != i:
        (lst[i], lst[curr]) = (lst[curr], lst[i])
        draw_attr.draw_list({i: draw_attr.GREEN, curr: draw_attr.RED}, True)
        heapify(draw_attr, n, curr, ascending)


def heap_sort(draw_attr, s_times, ascending=True):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    lst = draw_attr.lst

    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
        heapify(draw_attr, n, i, ascending)

    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        (lst[i], lst[0]) = (lst[0], lst[i])
        draw_attr.draw_list({i: draw_attr.GREEN, 0: draw_attr.RED}, True)
        heapify(draw_attr, i, 0, ascending)
        yield True

    s_times.heap = round(time.perf_counter() - start, 2)
    draw_attr.draw_times(s_times)


def bubble_sort(draw_attr, s_times, ascending=True):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    lst = draw_attr.lst

    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        for j in range(len(lst) - i - 1):
            num1 = lst[j]
            num2 = lst[j + 1]

            if (num1 > num2 and ascending) or (num1 < num2 and not ascending):
                lst[j], lst[j + 1] = lst[j + 1], lst[j]
                draw_attr.draw_list({j: draw_attr.GREEN, j + 1: draw_attr.RED}, True)
                yield True

    s_times.bubble = round(time.perf_counter() - start, 2)
    draw_attr.draw_times(s_times)


def main():
    run = True
    n = 100
    min_val = 0
    max_val = 100

    lst, seed = generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val)
    draw_attr = DrawAttributes(800, 600, lst)

    sorting = False
    ascending = True

    sorting_algorithm = insertion_sort
    sorting_algorithm_name = "Insertion Sort"
    sorting_algorithm_generator = None

    s_times = SortingTimes()

    while run:
        # pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
        if sorting:
            try:
                next(sorting_algorithm_generator)
            except StopIteration:
                sorting = False
        else:
            draw_attr.draw(sorting_algorithm_name, ascending, s_times)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type != pygame.KEYDOWN:
                continue
            if event.key == pygame.K_n:  # new list
                lst, seed = generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val)
                draw_attr.set_list(lst)
                s_times.clear()
                sorting = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_r:  # reset list
                lst, seed = generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val, True, seed)
                draw_attr.set_list(lst)
                sorting = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not sorting:
                sorting = True
                sorting_algorithm_generator = sorting_algorithm(draw_attr, s_times, ascending)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_a and not sorting:
                ascending = True

            elif event.key == pygame.K_d and not sorting:
                ascending = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_i and not sorting:
                sorting_algorithm = insertion_sort
                sorting_algorithm_name = "Insertion Sort"

            elif event.key == pygame.K_h and not sorting:
                sorting_algorithm = heap_sort
                sorting_algorithm_name = "Heap Sort"

            elif event.key == pygame.K_b and not sorting:
                sorting_algorithm = bubble_sort
                sorting_algorithm_name = "Bubble Sort"
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```